# grails - how can you force update a sub-dependency

Tags: grails

Due to a security issue with org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all i need to update it within a grails project. the issue is that it is being used by org.grails:grails-bootstrap and i am unable to update that, because it is never explicitly imported in my buildconfig.groovy file.

grails-bootstrap is currently importing org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6 and i need it to use org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.13

is there any way to update only the sub-dependency? is there any way to force a new version of org.grails:grails-bootstrap.

any help would be appreciated.

edit: i am on grails version 2.4.3 and dont want to make the upgrade to 3.x.x

Answer (score 1):

You can add an explicit dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: Be aware that using a version of Groovy that a particular version of Grails has not been validated against may or may not cause problems.

Comment: Also, make sure you are minding the difference between `groovy` and `groovy-all`.